# How to use save method with array inputs in larvel5.0

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

I want to save all array inputs to database using save method in laravel

HTML form

```
 <form>
       <input class="form-control" name="amount[]" type="text"/>
       <input class="form-control" name="price[]" type="text"/>
 </form>
```

I have used Javascript

```
var data = $('#form_A').serializeArray();
```

PHP

```
$cust = new customer();
$all_input = Request::input();
foreach($all_input as $k=>$vals) {
     $data[] = ['amount'=>$vals];
}

$cust = $data;
$cust->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$customer = new Customer();

$customer->fill($request->only($customer->getFillable()));

$customer->save();
```

`->getFillable()` will return the fillable values that you've stated in your customer model, using this with `$request->only()` results in an array having only the key + value pairs that the model can fill. and then `->fill()` speaks for itself :)

Answer (score 0):

With this line

```
$cust = $data;
```

you don't have anymore an object of class customer, but an array, so calling save() on it gives you an error "calling a method save() on not object".

I have no idea how your schema looks like, but if you want to fill a model with data from the array then you can either use fill() method (that requires to specify these attributes in $fillable or you can assign them one by one:

```
$cust->amount = $data['amount'];
$cust->price = $data['price'];
$cust->save();
```